# How can i use Google Cloud SQL to support multi-tenancy for my application

Tags: google-app-engine

How can i use Google Cloud SQL to support multi-tenancy for my application? I know that data-store supports namespace API bu what about Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/ datastore, memcache & taskqueue are the only things that supports namespace which is used by the multitenancy feature. Meaning stuff like blobstore and cloud sql you have to manually namespace or implement yourself.